# The cube does not rotate by pressing Vuforia virtual button in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I added the cube on the image target of Vuforia. I also added the virtual button on the image target. Now I want to rotate the cube by pressing virtual button. For this purpose I implemented the following script.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;

public class rotate : MonoBehaviour, IVirtualButtonEventHandler {

    public GameObject vbtn;
    public GameObject cube;
    public Renderer rend;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        vbtn = GameObject.Find ("virtualbtn5");
        vbtn.GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehaviour> ().RegisterEventHandler (this);
        cube = GameObject.Find ("Cube");
        rend = cube.GetComponent<Renderer>();   
    }

    public void OnButtonPressed(VirtualButtonBehaviour vb){

        Debug.Log ("Button pressed");
        cube.transform.Rotate (new Vector3(0,Time.deltaTime*1000,0));
        rend.material.color = Color.blue;

    }

    public void OnButtonReleased(VirtualButtonBehaviour vb){

        Debug.Log ("Button released");
        rend.material.color = Color.red;
    }       

}
```

The button seems to be working because the `Debug.Log ("Button pressed");` and `rend.material.color = Color.blue;` statements in `onButtonPressed` function are working fine. But `cube.transform.Rotate (new Vector3(0,Time.deltaTime*1000,0));` for rotating cube does not work.

Simple is that the button can change the color of the cube but it does not rotate the cube.

So the question is **How would I rotate the cube by pressing virtual button of vuforia.**

**Question Updated:**

I also tried the following code but still the cube does not rotate on button press.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;

public class rotate : MonoBehaviour, IVirtualButtonEventHandler {

    public GameObject vbtn;
    public GameObject cube;
    public Renderer rend;
    public bool rotateit;
    public float speed;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        vbtn = GameObject.Find ("virtualbtn5");
        vbtn.GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehaviour> ().RegisterEventHandler (this);
        cube = GameObject.Find ("Cube");
        speed = 100f;

        rend = cube.GetComponent<Renderer>();
        rotateit = false;


    }


    void Update(){


        if (rotateit) {

            cube.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, Time.deltaTime * speed, 0));
        }


    }


    public void OnButtonPressed(VirtualButtonBehaviour vb){

        //Debug.Log ("Button pressed");
        //cube.transform.RotateAround(cube.transform.position, new Vector3(0, 1, 0), 10000f * Time.deltaTime);
        //cube.transform.Rotate (new Vector3(0,Time.deltaTime*1000,0));
        rend.material.color = Color.blue;
        rotateit = true;
        Debug.Log ("Button pressed "+rotateit);

    }

    public void OnButtonReleased(VirtualButtonBehaviour vb){

        //Debug.Log ("Button released");
        rend.material.color = Color.red;
        rotateit = false;
        Debug.Log ("Button released "+rotateit);
    }



}
```

Also have a look at console window

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to rotate every frame while the button is held down but stop when released then use a boolean variable to do that. Set it to `true` in `OnButtonPressed` and `false` in `OnButtonReleased`. Check if this flag in `true` in the `Update` function then rotate the cube.

```
public GameObject vbtn;
public GameObject cube;
public Renderer rend;
bool pressed = false;
public float speed = 100f;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{

    vbtn = GameObject.Find("virtualbtn5");
    vbtn.GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehaviour>().RegisterEventHandler(this);
    cube = GameObject.Find("Cube");
    rend = cube.GetComponent<Renderer>();
}

public void OnButtonPressed(VirtualButtonBehaviour vb)
{

    Debug.Log("Button pressed");
    pressed = true;
    rend.material.color = Color.blue;

}

public void OnButtonReleased(VirtualButtonBehaviour vb)
{

    Debug.Log("Button released");
    pressed = false;
    rend.material.color = Color.red;
}

void Update()
{
    if (pressed)
        cube.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, Time.deltaTime * speed, 0));
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it does not work for me. sorry

Comment: The same solution work for simple UI buttons but not for Vuforia virtual button.

Comment: How is it even possible that it works for UI button but not for virtual button? Are you sure that those functions are being called at-all?

Comment: I just used the logic of boolean variables and transform.Rotate() on UI button, it work fine there...

Comment: The it should work with `OnButtonPressed`, Can you use just the `OnButtonPressed` and `OnButtonReleased` in my answer then upload a screenshot of the Console log tab. I want to see the log.

Comment: @SyedAun Ok. Is that log showing true|false when you press and hold or just true when pressed and false when released?

Comment: Didn't really answer the question.  Is that log showing true|false when you press and hold **or** just true when pressed and false when released

Comment: When I hold the button it show true and when I release the button it show false.

Comment: Ok. Inside `if (pressed)` put `Debug.Log("Rotating")` and tell me if that shows when button is pressed down

Comment: i did exactly as you said. " Rotating " also appeared multiple time in console log. so I think there is some problem with transforn.rotate() function.

Comment: It shouldn't appear just "multiple times". It should appear **Every** frame when held that. Does it stop or is it appearing every frame?

Comment: yes the message appear on every frame. when i release the button it stop the message "rotating"

Comment: Thanks bro for being so helpful. The problem fixed by creating a new unity project and using same script in it. So there was some problem with the old unity project.

Comment: I was in shock that didn't work. Glad you got it working.